# simulating an change event jquery

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I have five lists (select) that are populated with php / mysql and jquery. I use this script: http://bit.ly/3YTAXe

When I post my form and the new page appears, I redisplay my five list and I want my 5 lists will populate with the values ​​posted.

I think I'd have to simulate the event "change" or something like that.
I do not think my code can help (it's inside the smarty and many other things).

Does anyone can help me from the example code that is in the link above?

Comment: have you tried `$('#yourselect').trigger('change');` ?

Comment: How can I do to simulate the event by choosing the right value? Because it is based on the value that my second list will be populated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#yourselect').val('yourvalue');
$('#yourselect').trigger('change');
```

It can also be chained into a single statement:

```
$('#yourselect').val('yourvalue').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

a standard post action ask the server for a new page, which has no natural "memory" of the the form posted. So you have 3 basics options:

1. send the values back from your servers
2. use cookies to store them, and javacript to handle the cookies
3. use jquery $.post instead of the standard post.

I prefer the 3rd option. jquery will send the form in ajax, and handle the response from the server *inside* the actual page. Of course, you have to "event.preventDefault" on the form submit button click (or in $('form').submit). Personally, I don't define any "action=" tag in forms supposed to be sent by $.post (i use a variable inside the $.post block).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure it helps someone =)